# How do I get a Seraph Crystal?

Tags: borderlands-2

There's someone much like Crazy Earl in Oasis behind a locked door. He tells me to leave until I've killed a seraph guardian or I get some sort of guardian crystal.

I just beat the DLC and did many of the sidequests and I'm still stumped as to how to get such a crystal. I assumed there would be Guardian foes just like in Borderlands 1, and they'd drop this item. After completing the story...there were no such enemies. So what do I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get crystals from both Hyperius and Master Gee the Invincible. Both of these fights are more tactical than complicated, and can be really difficult to do without an experienced team. Both of these bosses have quests that lead to them, after you beat the main story for the DLC.

Each boss drops ~10 crystals each. This is painstakingly low, as a weapon in the Seraph Vendor will cost you 120 shard, where as the Relic (always the Item of the Day) will cost you 50 crystals. The Relic is an upgraded version of the Blood of Terramorphous, giving both health regen and increased max health. The weapons are, stat-wise, pretty useless for the price, but can be a (slight) upgrade to the weapons you may have now.

Every one of the pink "Seraph" items have a red text, including the relic and Shield. As of yet, nobody has figured out what the red effects are.

Note that, since a recent update, you'll have to defeat these bosses on True Vault Hunter mode to get crystals. They'll be easier but won't drop crystals in Normal Mode.

Voracidous the Invincible from the Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt DLC and the Ancient Dragons of Destruction from the Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep DLC also have a chance of dropping crystals upon defeating them.

Comment: Pete the Invincible in the TORGUE DLC also drops seraph crystals. I haven't played it yet but I'm assuming whatever 'invincible' there is in the third DLC will also drop them.

Comment: Do crystals still drop in TVHM? It's been two years and just wanted to know

Comment: Since the addition of UVHM difficulty, Seraph crystals only drop there.

Answer (score 1):

You get a quest to kill Hyperius the Invincible after finishing the story. Hyperius and Master Gee drop crystals.

Comment: You can kill hyperius if you get a Social Conference Call (orange level 50 shotgun) The Warrior drops this randomly, but if its used with The Bee Dropped from Hunter Helquist after completing this just in! it does TONS of damage to any thing, I did the same for master gee, hope it helped