# Borderlands 2 Seraph crystals

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a Seraph Crystal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89213/how-do-i-get-a-seraph-crystal)

I have completed the main story line for the Pirate DLC. I have also killed (solo'ed) Gee and Hyperious at least twice on different days and I havent seen a seraph crystal yet. Have I missed something or done something wrong?